# How do i fix this dynamic query parameter in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a URL to have a dynamic parameter based on the value of a variable.

Here's what Im doing

```
echo "The file name is ".$value.'<a href="filespecificpage.php?filename=<?php echo $value ?>">'.$value.'</a>'."<br>";
```

However, when I click on the corresponding link I get the following URL in the browser
`http://localhost/HelloWorld/filespecificpage.php?filename=<?php echo $value ?>` rather than the actual value in `$value`. Any help on how I can fix this would be appreciated.

PHP Noob here, appreciate the patience.

Comment: why is there a -1? Bad question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already in PHP script mode, you don't need `<?php`. You just need to concatenate the variable, like you did earlier in the line. You should also use `urlencode()` when substituting a variable into a URL parameter.

```
echo "The file name is ".$value.'<a href="filespecificpage.php?filename=' . urlencode($value) . '">'.$value.'</a>'."<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you break the PHP String/Echo dont use the doublequotes, it makes your live much harder as you need ist.

For your question

```
echo 'The file name is ' . $value . '<a href="filespecificpage.php?filename=' . urlencode($value) .  '>' . $value . '</a><br>';
```

An expample why single and not doublequotes. If you write an Hyperlink in HTML you use

```
<a href="website" target="_blank">Link description</a>
```

and all is fine. 
If you do it in an PHP echo with doublequotes you must escape all quotes.

```
echo "<a href=\"website\" target=\"_blank\">Link description</a>";
```

Perfect look and way

```
echo '<a href="website" target="_blank" ' . $anyPHPvar . '>Link description</a>';
```

and you can use " for clear html and ' for PHP ;)

So, use singlequotes makes your life easyer and its a little bit faster and welcome to PHP ;)